# Trouble finding components using python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am very new to Selenium and am trying to scrape data off of the following webstie: https://www.ahla.com/statefacts. The website keeps data about hotels around the US. The ultimate goal of what I am trying to do is to create a csv file the would contain a column called 'States' and the other columns would be data in regards to the hotels in them (i.e. # of hotels, # of hotel rooms, etc.)

I was thinking that I would access the  dropdown that contains all the states and sequentially click through them and extract the data, but I cannot even find the select dropdown.

Here is the code I am running that gives me a NoSuchElementException:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.ahla.com/statefacts")

print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#next > div > div > div.col-md-5 > h1 > div > div > select"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iframe is present on the page .you need to switch on the iframe before you interact with drop down element.

```
driver.get("https://www.ahla.com/statefacts")


driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys("Keys.ESCAPE")
iframe=driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
element=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='select-state__select']/option[text()='Alabama']"))).click()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I do have a follow up question though. So what you have above correctly leads be to the page containing data about Alabama. Now I am trying to access the "HOTEL GUESTROOMS IN AL (NUMBER OF ROOMS)" value. Would I need to do something like: ```aval_guestrooms = element.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div").text()```

Comment: In addition, I noticed that you xpath you get on the select is much different than mine. When I click on "Copy Full Xpath" on Chrome for the select dropdown, I get ```/html/body/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/h1/div/div/select/option[1]```. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="linked-stat__stat"]'))) dont forget again element in the iframe

Comment: I have not checked you xpath tbh .. its absolute xpath which i never preferred

Comment: Thank you again! Sorry for the continuous responses. I am still struggling a little to get the actual text. '//div[@class="linked-stat__stat"]' gives me a WebElement and I cannot get the text from the WebElement. In addition, as you probably noticed, all of the numbers of the page only have the class linked-stat__stat so I tried to subscript the elements in order to get the 3rd one but that also gave me an error

Comment: I actually was able to get it when I removed the wait and added .get_attribute("innerHTML")!